# Ant: renaming a group of files subject to a condition

Tags: ant

I'm using Ant 1.8.2. Given a directory, how do I add an ".html" extension to all files in the directory and its sub-directories only if those files don't already have an .html extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example in the Ant [`move` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) docs for renaming `.bak` files that is similar, here it is adjusted for `.html` files under a directory called `my_dir`:

```
<move todir="my_dir" includeemptydirs="false">
    <fileset dir="my_dir">
        <exclude name="**/*.html" />
    </fileset>
    <mapper type="glob" from="*" to="*.html" />
</move>
```

The fileset excludes files that already have the target extension, the mapper defines the renaming pattern.